# How exactly is 12 month period calculated for AWS free tier

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've registered on 30 July 2018. Does that mean July is my 1st month and at the end of June 2019 my free tier will expire, or I will have free tier until 30 July 2019?

In other words, do they calculate 12 months from date to date, or month by month?

Comment: @torazaburo You obviously didn't even read my question, but downvoted both question and everyone answers... Yes, it expires 12 months from date you sign up, which can have multiple meanings, which is what I asked in the question. Btw, you really think I haven't thoroughly read the FAQ and tried google before I came here to ask this?

Comment: His question is perfectly valid, as even though the FAQ you linked mentions "The AWS free usage tier will expire 12 months from the date you sign up" it still appears be ambiguous since it isn't clearly mentioned Date-to-Date. The information appears obvious once you know it. 

Also, based on Stack Overflow's FAQ's "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." his question fits perfectly and since there was no previous answer to it, it adds to the community pool of knowledge.

Comment: @RhythemAggarwal We'll see what the moderators think. The ToS of some commercial service are NOT on-topic here, at all, and never have been, and never will be. As for the point in question, I know everyone is not a native speaker, but "expire 12 months from the date you sign up" cannot possibly, by any stretch of the imagination, be interpreted in any way other than "expire on a date 12 months from the date you sign up" (the word "date" refers to a specific day), in other words, it is 1000% obvious that this means date-to-date.

Comment: I agree with everything you said. I was just bringing the one assumption that you made - "what AWS FAQs mentions is obvious to all".However it COULD be ambiguous to some people, and based on the FAQ of stack overflow, such questions (if not answered already) are valid. Again, i agree with you that moderators will decide. i am not trying to pick a fight with you, just presenting my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's calculated date to date. ie. Your free tier will expire on 30 July 2019. AWS services are priced usually per minute, or even per second. Nothing is charged for full month, if you don't use it. Only thing is that they charge it at the end of the month, so for example, it could happen if you have some provisioned services, that are under free tier, and don't shut them down before July 30th 2019, that in July invoice you are charged beause they would have 2 days of usage after free tier expires (July 1-29 it's in free tier, so no charge, 30-31 free tier expired, and you are charged for usage)

Also, you will receive email from AWS about a month before your free tier expires, so they will notify you of such upfront

Comment: Thanks man! This answers my question completely.